# Between any two real numbers, there is an algebraic number and also a transcendental number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, transcendental-numbers

Between any two real numbers, there is an algebraic number and also a transcendental number. 
I understand what algebraic numbers and transcendental numbers are, but how can I prove that they both exist between any two real numbers?

Comment: For the first part just use the fact that every rational number is algebraic. Now for the second, if there are $x,y\in\mathbb R$ with $x<y$ such that $(x,y)$ contains only algebraic numbers then $(x,y)$ is countable

Comment: http://math.stackexchange/questions/1690121/is-there-an-easy-enough-way-to-show-that-between-two-algebraic-numbers-there-is

Comment: @AdamHughes Your link is broken. You typed in `math.stackechange/` instead of `math.stackechange.com/`.

Answer (score 22):

Here's one way to do it without doing too much work, assuming you already know that between any two reals there is a *rational*:

- Every rational is algebraic; so, between any two reals, there is an algebraic real.
- Meanwhile, the set of algebraic numbers is countable, but every nonempty interval $(x, y)$ is uncountable. So "most" elements of $(x, y)$ are transcendental - in particular, there's at least one! So between any two reals, there's a transcendental, as well.

Answer (score 20):

Hint: rational numbers are algebraic, and (non-zero) rational multiples of $\pi$ are trancendental.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a concrete example of how to *construct* a rational $q$ and a transcendental $t$ between two real numbers $r_1$ and $r_2$.

Take the decimal expansions of the two real numbers $r_1$ and $r_2$. At some point (say the $n$th digit) they must differ (otherwise they are the same number).

Now take the number composed of the first $n$ digits of $r_2$. As it has a finite decimal expansion it is rational, and clearly it falls between $r_1$ and $r_2$. Call it $q$.

To obtain a transcendental number in the range, look at the difference $r_2 - q$ and find a positive rational less than this difference (say by taking its decimal expansion as far as the first nonzero digit). Call it $d$.

Consider a value $x = \frac{\pi d}{4}$. This is transcendental and $0 < x < d$. Therefore $t = q + x$ is also transcendental and $r_1 < t < r_2$.

Comment: you mean "take a decimal expansion for each of the two real numbers..."

Comment: What if the first digit of $r_2$ differing from $r_1$ is also the last non-zero digit of $r_2$? Then you would have $q = r_2$. Of course there will always be a number $r$ with finite decimal expansion such that $r_1<r<r_2$, and it should be easy enough to tweak this procedure to find such a number.

Answer (score 4):

Def'n: A set $T\subset  \mathbb R$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ iff $T\cap (a,b)\ne \emptyset$ whenever $a<b.$

If $x$ is transcendental and $y$ is rational then $x+y$ is transcendental.

If $S$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ and $x\in \mathbb R$ then $x+S=\{x+y:y\in S\}$ is dense in $\mathbb R.$

So take transcendental $x$ and $S=\mathbb Q.$ Then $T=x+S$ is  a dense set of trancendentals.

Answer (score 0):

The density of the algebraic numbers $\mathbb A$ in $\mathbb R$ follows immediately from the fact that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, and $\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb A$.

Now let $x$ be a transcendental number, and let $a<b$. Since $a-x<b-x$, there is a $y\in\mathbb A$ such that $a-x<y<b-x$. Hence $a<x+y<b$, with $x+y$ transcendental.